# Battery for GPRS module and voltage regulation

Tags: battery-charging, dc-dc-converter, lipo, gsm, buck-boost

I work on a wearable GSM device powered with a LiPo battery.

I want to use a switching charger with a power path. My GSM module can consume up to 2 amps during data transmission and its working voltage lies between 3.5 V and 4.2 V. Also, I use a boost converter with a passthrough which works only when the battery level becomes low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGkEST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But here is a problem with the charger. All of the models with regulated system voltage (SYS) make it slightly higher than battery voltage while charging. It could be about 4.5 V.

**And it's higher than maximum modem voltage. :(**

How to deal with it? I don’t want to use a buck-boost converter, just for the charging period. They have lesser efficiency and higher cost. Now I want to try a diode with MOSFET to drop some voltage on it.

[image]

But it looks overcomplicated... Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please show a diagram of your setup. (you can also use the circuit tool to draw one, it will draw boxes)

Comment: The standard chargers are buck but you need battery current feedback in CC mode if you plan on using it in this mode and not battery + load current.

Comment: I've clarified the question.